# How to calculate distance between a point and an intersection line in python?

Tags: python, math, scipy

I am rusty in my math, not sure how to calculate the distrance from the highest point H to the intersection between the 2 lowest points in the middle for the N point.

[image: Picture of the Chart]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np

y= [10.5,10,12,13,10,11,16,10,9,13,10]
x= np.linspace(1, len(y), len(y), endpoint=True)
dist = np.linalg.norm(y-x)

print dst

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.plot(x, y, color='red')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import heapq
import operator
import math


y = [10.5,10,12,13,10,11,16,10,9,13,10]
x= np.linspace(1, len(y), len(y), endpoint=True)

y1,y2 = heapq.nsmallest(2, enumerate(y), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
x1,y1 = y1
x1 = x[x1]

x2,y2 = y2
x2 = x[x2]

m = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
print("Equation of line: y = {}(x-{}) + {}".format(m, x1, y1))

apexPoint = (5,4)  # or wherever the apex point is    
X,Y = apexPoint
M = 1/m
print("Equation of perpendicular line: y = {}(x-{}) + {}".format(M, X, Y))

intersect_x = ((M*X)+Y-(m*x1)-y1)/(M-m)
intersect_y = m*(intersect_x - x1) + y1

dist = math.sqrt((X - intersect_x)**2 + (Y - intersect_y)**2)  # this is your answer
```

Comment: You do realize that perpendicular would look very different from the image in the question. The foot of the perpendicular would be at around (2.5, 10.5). It won't have the same x intercept as the apex point.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your chart. The line is not perpendicular. It is a vertical line from a point to a line segment.

Assuming your apex point is (x0,y0) and your base points are (x1,y1) and (x2,y2):

The equation of the line joining 2 points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) is:

```
y = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) * x + (y2 * (x2-x1) - x1 * (y2-y1)) / (x2-x1)
```

Get the y intercept on the the line:

```
ymid = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) * x0 + (y2 * (x2-x1) - x1 * (y2-y1)) / (x2-x1)
```

Your distance is:

```
y0 - ymid
```

See http://pythonfiddle.com/SO-33162756/

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question directly but perhaps you would want to checkout the **awesome** python module `shapely`.

You can create geometric objects such as `LineStrings`, `Points` using the module.

And a simple call to:

> object.project(other[, normalized=False])
>
> Returns the distance along this geometric object to a point nearest
>   the other object.

will give you your answer.

Here's its documentation:
[Shapely Documentation](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html)